# How to Convert Folder to byte[] and again byte[] to Folder

Tags: c#

any idea how can I do this I dnt want to manage bytes[] of each files of folder.

Thanx

Comment: Your question makes no sense, please clarify.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to convert a *collection* of files into a *single* byte array?

Comment: You might want to create an archive containing a folder. That way you could work with that folder as a byte[]

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed as I have the same problem (even though BreakHead could have been more specific). The question is: how to have the contents of a directory as a byte array? The answer is straightforward as well, read everything and then somehow structure that in memory (perhaps structure everything in objects and then serialize them to byte arrays), however would be nice to know what's around that addresses this need.

Answer (score 1):

The question makes no sense. Folders do not have any binary content, only files do. You will need to enumerate all files in the folder and open them separately.